# SSIS Logging - Not able to see checkboxes in treeview of container pane

Tags: logging, ssis

I am using VS 2022 Professional Edition with its SSDT.
In SSIS package I am developing, while enabling logging feature, I couldn’t see checkboxes in Container pane to enable the logging.
Is there any setting that should be done for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. It should be the Known issue for VS2022.

From the link below, the known issues for Version 0.2

8. **Logging container can't choose packages**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/ssdt/release-notes-integration-services-2022?view=sql-server-ver16